# How can I find the originally matched route at the time of a request in Express.Js

Tags: regex, node.js, express, routes

I need to recover the original route at the time of a request. Either the original one with the :Variable strings, or the regular expression. Basically I want to have some key that groups all requests that hit the same route in a generic, high-level pre-processor.

The problem is that my routes are fairly complex with nested apps and routers, so app.routes.map doesn't contain the routes.

Is there a way to reverse engineer the route from the request object, or is there a place where I can get a global list of routes that I could match and search agaisnt the current request?

Comment: The output from console.dir(Object.keys(req)) is:
`[ '_readableState',
  'readable',
  'domain',
  '_events',
  '_maxListeners',
  'socket',
  'connection',
  'httpVersion',
  'complete',
  'headers',
  'trailers',
  '_pendings',
  '_pendingIndex',
  'url',
  'method',
  'statusCode',
  'client',
  '_consuming',
  '_dumped',
  'httpVersionMajor',
  'httpVersionMinor',
  'upgrade',
  'originalUrl',
  '_parsedUrl',
  'query',
  'res',
  'next' ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific route should be available in `req.route` ([docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.route)). That contains several properties, including `req.route.regexp` (the compiled regular expression for the route), and `req.route.params` (array of matched parameters).

**EDIT:** The route isn’t going to be attached until the request is dispatched.

It sounds like you’re trying to predict the route before it’s dispatched. In that case, using `app.routes` might normally work. The problem is that you have sub-apps with their own routers. `app.routes` only contains routes for the top-level `app` and not for any sub-apps.

The answer is: **There is no global view of routes.** Your sub-apps look exactly like middleware to the parent app. It does not know or care that there is routing going on down there.

If you need to do this, you have to do it manually, e.g., create a global array where you register your sub-apps.

Comment: req.route is undefined. I am executing this inside an app.use handler, but this app does not directly contain the routes. They are loaded from seperate routers using new express.Router() and app.use(..., router.middleware);

Comment: @Killroy, if you are trying to figure out the routes before they are dispatched, there is no way to do that automatically. You have to manually keep track of them. See updated answer.

Comment: That was my work around in the end. I wonder if there was a way to run the routing process on the URL before hand some how.